# CountDownTimer issue

Tags: android

Basically my aim is to have this timer reset whenever the user presses button `b`. I've tried a few methods such as `if( i==true && bIsPressed())` but no luck, any ideas?

```
//2 buttons

Button =b;
TextView = time;

//countdown code

    CountDownTimer Count = new CountDownTimer(11000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        time.setText(""+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        time.setText("Finished");
    }

    }; Count.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but I would do something along the lines of:

```
private void setupTimerResetButton()
{
    mTimerResetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(){
            resetTimer();
        }
    });
}

private void resetTimer()
{
    if(mTimer != null){
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer = null;
    }
    mTimer = new CountDownTimer(11000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimerTextView.setText(""+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerTextView.setText("Finished");
        }
    }; 
    mTimer.start();
}
```